# Vue component template not render when used with @if in blade,php

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

I have created Vue template which works fine when it is not used inside @if , but it return black  if used inside @if.
Here is my template

```
<template>
    <div>
        <usage-token-button :tokens="usageTokens" v-on:use-token="useComplimentaryToken">
            <template v-slot:default="data">
                <span class="d-inline-block">
                    ABC
                </span>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:use-button>ABC</template>
        </usage-token-button>

        <usage-token-button :tokens="researchPasses" v-on:use-token="useResearchPassToken">
            <template v-slot:default="data">
                <span class="d-inline-block">
                    ABC
                </span>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:use-button>ABC</template>
        </usage-token-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

and this is how it is called

```
@if(!isset($showdata))
    <usage-token-access
        doi="{{ $content->metaInfo()['content']->doi }}"
        root="{{ config('app.subdir') ? config('app.subdir') : '/' }}">
    </usage-token-access>
@endif
```

I have confirmed it is going inside if condition , and when I inspect it I can see blank div [as show in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEuDf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you paste `<usage-token-button>` component template?

Comment: I only have limited experience with blade.html, but I believe the problem could be that the delimiters, ie.  {{  }}, are reserved when inside a php function like for or if. You may be able to fix this by adding new delimiters and changing the ones in your blade template, something like:

delimiters: ['<%', '%>']